# How to resubmit thread to ExecutorService if it failed/finished

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a Thread that must be resubmitted every time its job is finished or crashed due an error.

The main thread must not be blocked.

Threads must be cancelled if necessary.

What is the best solution ?

```
public class POC {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Init");
    new SomeService().waitForEvents();
    System.out.println("main not blocked and do other stuff");
}

static class SomeService {
    public void waitForEvents() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(new AlwaysRunningJob("importantParamForJob"));
        // MISSING LOGIC 
        //    // if AlwaysRunningJob got error or finished,
        //    // wait 2 seconds recreate and resubmit it
        //    executor.submit(new AlwaysRunningJob("importantParamForJob"));
    }

    class AlwaysRunningJob implements Runnable {
        String importantParamForJob;

        public AlwaysRunningJob(String importantParamForJob) {
            this.importantParamForJob = importantParamForJob;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("AlwaysRunningJob Job");
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // keep waiting for events until
                // exception is thrown. or something bad happened
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("keep working on" + importantParamForJob);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // exit if it failed
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Finished run!");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe you can use UncaughtExceptionHandler for that Thread which will catch the exception and resubmit the Thread again?

Comment: You do not submit threads to executors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would extends ThreadPoolExecutor that will implements the `protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)` by default this method doesn't do anything but you could do something like:

```
public class RetryExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    private final long maxRetries;
    private Map<Runnable, Integer> retries = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public RetryExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long maxRetries,
                     long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        if (t != null && shouldRetry(r)) {
            retry(r);
        }  else if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
            try {
                ((Future<?>) r).get();
            } catch (CancellationException | ExecutionException e) {
                // you should log the error
                if (shouldRetry(r)) {
                    retry(r);
                } else {
                    retries.remove(r);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset or catch it to reschedule
            }
        } else {
            retries.remove(r);
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldRetry(Runnable r) {
        final Integer nbRetries = retries.getOrDefault(r, 0);
        return nbRetries < maxRetries;
    }

    private void retry(Runnable r) {
        final Integer nbRetries = retries.getOrDefault(r, 0);
        retries.put(r, nbRetries + 1);
        this.execute(r);
    }

}
```

But with this Future are useless it's more like a fire and forget.

As @NikitataGorbatchevski it won't work when you use a Callable. So here is a version that can handle both using Runnable and Callable. Indead FutureTask can't be run again if an error occurs (I reused code for waiting termination from FutureTask and not so sure about it):

```
public class RetryExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
    private final long maxRetries;
    private Map<Runnable, Integer> retries = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public RetryExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long maxRetries,
                         long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
        this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
        return new RetryFutureTask<>(runnable, value);
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
        return new RetryFutureTask<>(callable);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        if (t != null && shouldRetry(r)) {
            retry(r);
        }  else if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
            try {
                Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
            } catch (CancellationException | ExecutionException e) {
                // you should log the error
                if (shouldRetry(r)) {
                    retry(r);
                }  else {
                    retries.remove(r);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // ignore/reset
            }
        } else {
            retries.remove(r);
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldRetry(Runnable r) {
        final Integer nbRetries = retries.getOrDefault(r, 0);
        return nbRetries < maxRetries;
    }

    private void retry(Runnable r) {
        final Integer nbRetries = retries.getOrDefault(r, 0);
        retries.put(r, nbRetries + 1);
        this.execute(r);
    }

    private static class RetryFutureTask<V> implements RunnableFuture<V> {
        private static final int NEW = 0;
        private static final int RUNNING = 1;
        private static final int ERROR = 2;
        private static final int FINISHED = 3;
        private static final int INTERRUPTED = 4;
        private final AtomicInteger state = new AtomicInteger(NEW);
        private final AtomicReference<Thread> runner = new AtomicReference<>();
        private final AtomicReference<WaitNode> waiters = new AtomicReference<>();
        private final Callable<V> callable;
        private Exception error;
        private V result;

        public RetryFutureTask(Runnable runnable, V result) {
            this.callable = Executors.callable(runnable, result);
        }

        public RetryFutureTask(Callable<V> callable) {
            this.callable = callable;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // If not already running
                if (runner.compareAndSet(null, Thread.currentThread())) {
                    state.set(RUNNING);
                    result = this.callable.call();
                    state.compareAndSet(RUNNING, FINISHED);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                error = e;
                state.compareAndSet(RUNNING, ERROR);
                finishCompletion();
            } finally {
                runner.set(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            if (state.get() == RUNNING || state.get() == INTERRUPTED) {
                return false;
            }
            try {
                Thread t = runner.get();
                if (mayInterruptIfRunning && t != null) {
                    t.interrupt();
                }
            } finally {
                state.set(INTERRUPTED);
                finishCompletion();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCancelled() {
            return state.get() == INTERRUPTED;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDone() {
            return state.get() > RUNNING;
        }

        @Override
        public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            if (state.get() <= RUNNING) {
                awaitDone(false, 0L);
            }
            return resolve();
        }

        @Override
        public V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
            if (state.get() <= RUNNING) {
                awaitDone(true, unit.toNanos(timeout));
            }
            return resolve();
        }

        private V resolve() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            if (state.get() == ERROR) {
                throw new ExecutionException(error);
            } else if (state.get() == INTERRUPTED) {
                throw new InterruptedException();
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void finishCompletion() {
            for (WaitNode q; (q = waiters.get()) != null;) {
                if (waiters.compareAndSet(q, null)) {
                    for (;;) {
                        Thread t = q.thread;
                        if (t != null) {
                            q.thread = null;
                            LockSupport.unpark(t);
                        }
                        WaitNode next = q.next;
                        if (next == null)
                            break;
                        q.next = null; // unlink to help gc
                        q = next;
                    }
                break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void awaitDone(boolean timed, long nanos) throws InterruptedException {
            final long deadline = timed ? System.nanoTime() + nanos : 0L;
            WaitNode q = null;
            boolean queued = false;
            for (; ; ) {
                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    removeWaiter(q);
                    throw new InterruptedException();
                }

                int s = state.get();
                if (s > RUNNING) {
                    if (q != null)
                        q.thread = null;
                    return;
                } else if (q == null)
                    q = new WaitNode();
                else if (!queued)
                    queued = waiters.compareAndSet(q.next, q);
                else if (timed) {
                    nanos = deadline - System.nanoTime();
                    if (nanos <= 0L) {
                        removeWaiter(q);
                        return;
                    }
                    LockSupport.parkNanos(this, nanos);
                } else
                    LockSupport.park(this);
            }
        }

        private void removeWaiter(WaitNode node) {
            if (node != null) {
                node.thread = null;
                retry:
                for (;;) {          // restart on removeWaiter race
                    for (WaitNode pred = null, q = waiters.get(), s; q != null; q = s) {
                        s = q.next;
                        if (q.thread != null)
                            pred = q;
                        else if (pred != null) {
                            pred.next = s;
                            if (pred.thread == null) // check for race
                                continue retry;
                        }
                        else if (!waiters.compareAndSet(q, s))
                            continue retry;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        static final class WaitNode {
            volatile Thread thread;
            volatile WaitNode next;
            WaitNode() { thread = Thread.currentThread(); }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JEY, your solution seems to be the best for me.

Comment: Did you guys try to run it? As actual type of `Runnable` `r` is a `FutureTask` rerunning it doesn't have effect as the result if already computed. If you add some logging to `afterExecute()` method you will see that this method invokes for `nbRetries` times and exit without actual rerunning of original task. If you will try to rerun successfully finished task with this logic you will get infinite loop what is even worse.

Comment: @NikitaGorbachevski don't understand your comment. The retry will occur only when an exception is raised during the execution. However the Future returned by the first submit is the result of the first execution and not updated after. It more a fire and forget with retry

Comment: When you run `this.execute(r)` in `retry(r)` you return immediately with the same `r` and the same result, the second task with original Runnable isn't invoked.

Comment: yes you are right i'll look into it i'm afraid that you need to override execute/schedule

Comment: I made it work with reflection, if you want i can share code sample. Your idea is really beautiful but unfortunately it's pretty complex to implement in practice.

Comment: I updated my answer to take into account your review. The hard part is to implements a RunnableFuture (the waiting part, i past it from FutureTask)

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, here is a simple solution (with a lot of hopefully helpful comment) that does not involve extending an Executor or writing Thread/sleep handling (which is easy to get very wrong...).

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;

import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;
import static java.util.concurrent.Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

/**
 * This is an example for task re-scheduling using {@link ScheduledExecutorService}. If you copy this for actual use make
 * <em>sure to to manage the lifecycle</em> of the {@link RetryingJobExecutor}. It needs to be shut down when your app shuts down.
 * Also consider the thread pool size of the executor service.
 */
class Scratch {
    // We'll just use this to simulate job behavior.
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random(currentTimeMillis());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

        RetryingJobExecutor retryingExecutor = new RetryingJobExecutor();

        Callable<String> potentiallyFailingJob = () -> {
            if (shouldFail()) {
                System.out.println("Job fails");
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            System.out.println("Job succeeds");
            return "result";
        };

        Future<String> result = retryingExecutor.execute(potentiallyFailingJob);

        System.out.println("Job scheduled, awaiting result...");
        System.out.println("Job completed and returned: " + result.get());

        retryingExecutor.shutdown();
    }

    public static class RetryingJobExecutor {
        // We are using a scheduled executor so we can define an arbitrary re-execution delay
        // without having to care for Thread.sleep + InterruptedExceptions etc.
        // Since this service is single-threaded, only one job will be executed at a time (this is not relevant
        // to this example, though).
        private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        public <K> Future<K> execute(Callable<K> task) {
            // Submit the task for asap execution. We will
            // use a CompletableFuture to provide the result when
            // the job eventually succeeds.
            final CompletableFuture<K> f = new CompletableFuture<>();
            executorService.submit(() -> runUntilSuccess(task, f));
            return f;
        }

        private <K> void runUntilSuccess(Callable<K> task, CompletableFuture<K> f) {
            try {
                f.complete(task.call());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // This is where we decide whether to re-schedule a job.

                // It is important to consider what to catch here. For instance, catching "Exception"
                // Will also catch "InterruptedException". However, if you have a task that might be interrupted,
                // You might actually want to terminate the task, since Interruption may signal that a shutdown is in progress.
                // Catching Exception also does not catch all Exceptions - Throwable might not get caught, e.g. NoSuchMethod errors.
                // However, these usually represent unresolvable programming errors.

                // For simplicity we will simply re-submit the task with arbitrary delay.
                // Note that this does not mean the job will be executed exactly after the delay.
                // The task will be executed when the delay has passed and an executor thread becomes available.
                executorService.schedule(() -> runUntilSuccess(task, f), 1, SECONDS);
            }
        }

        public void shutdown() {
            // Never forget that executor services create and run threads, and *must* be shut down for an app to terminate properly.
            executorService.shutdownNow();
        }
    }

    private static boolean shouldFail() {
        return RANDOM.nextInt(10) < 8;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with the ExecutorService I would switch from `Runnable` to `Callable`. When submitting a `Callable` you get a `Future` you can get the result (or Exception) of the job code in the `Callable`.

Therefore you can detect if the job has been executed successfully or not and re-submit the job if you need:

```
static class SomeService {
    public void waitForEvents() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Void> future = executor.submit(new AlwaysRunningJob("importantParamForJob"));

        try {
            future.get(); // this call waits until the Callable has finished (or failed)
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            // Error -> resubmit
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        // No error -> do something else
    }

    class AlwaysRunningJob implements Callable<Void> {
        String importantParamForJob;

        public AlwaysRunningJob(String importantParamForJob) {
            this.importantParamForJob = importantParamForJob;
        }

        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("AlwaysRunningJob Job");
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // keep waiting for events until
                // exception is thrown. or something bad happened
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    System.out.println("keep working on" + importantParamForJob);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // exit if it failed
                    return null;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Finished run!");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a separate thread waiting for the Future to complete. However to be honest an ExecutorService is the wrong way to implement. better use one dedicated Thread/Runnable in an endless loop. Alternatively a Time/TimerTask combination. There you would not have to re-schedule the tasks, instead it can be automatically executed every x miliseconds.

Comment: Timer/TimerTask combination is nice idea.

Comment: A timer task is brittle though to failures.  If it fails, it also causes the Timer to stop executing as well.  One of the disadvantages of using TimerTask unless you make it very resilient.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this one :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executorService.submit(new RepeatableWorker());

    System.out.println("Main does other work");
    Thread.sleep(3300);
    System.out.println("Main work was finished, time to exit");

    // shutdownNow interrupts running threads
    executorService.shutdownNow();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  public static class RepeatableWorker extends Worker {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        boolean error = false;
        Exception ex = null;
        try {
          // In some cases it's make sense to run this method in a separate thread.
          // For example if you want to give some time to the last worker thread to complete 
          // before interrupting it from repeatable worker
          super.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          error = true;
          ex = e;
        }

        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
          System.out.println("worker was interrupted");
          // just exit as last task was interrupted
          continue;
        }

        if (!error) {
          System.out.println("worker task was finished normally");
        } else {
          System.out.println("worker task was finished due to error " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        // wait some time before the next start
        try {
          Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          System.out.println("Repeatable worker was interrupted");
          // ok we were interrupted
          // restore interrupted status and exit
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
      }
      System.out.println("repeatable task was finished");
    }
  }

  public static class Worker implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        // emulate some work
        Thread.sleep(500L);
        if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
          throw new RuntimeException("ouch");
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // restore interrupted status
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  }
```